# git gc error: bad ref for __init__.py

Tags: git

Does anyone know why this error could be coming on git gc? Seems like related to a branch i had made by mistake.

```
$ git gc                                                                                                                                                                                            
error: bad ref for __init__.py
fatal: bad object refs/__init__.py
error: failed to run repack$ git gc
```

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you've created a file named `.git/refs/__init__.py`, i.e., you put a file into git's repository, but it's not in a form git can use.  You should move that file out of there (or remove it entirely).